# Алгоритм для быстрой проверки соответствия строки шаблонам?

Tags: алгоритм, строки, структуры-данных

В упрощенном виде задача такова: есть *большое* количество шаблонов из нулей и единиц. Возможен символ * *в конце* шаблона. ( Например: 1, 10, 1011* )

И есть *большое* количество строк. Для каждой строки необходимо проверить, "покрывается" ли строка каким-либо из шаблонов.

Вопрос: как это сделать наиболее эффективно? Наверняка есть какой-то известный алгоритм или структура данных для этой задачи.

Answer (score 2):

Для одновременного поиска множества шаблонов вам должен подойти [алгоритм Ахо-Корасик](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm).